# ordering results using mongoose in express

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose, ejs

I'm using mongoose to create and model my document schemas.

I have a user_id attribute on a bunch of different schemas, along with a created_at date attribute on them.

I want to generate a list, ordered by created_at date for display as a feed of recent activity on the user's homepage.

How would I query several different models, and then order these items into an array that I can then pass to my ejs view?

Answer (score 2):

You can sort your mongoose query using the [sort function](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#query_Query-sort). Here are two examples:

```
query.sort({ field: 'asc', test: -1 });
```

or

```
Person
  .find({user_id: 123456})
  .sort('-created_at')
  .exec(function(err, person) {
    // push these results to your array and start another query on a different schema
  });
```

Comment: This is good, but I want to collect a bunch of different items. Person.find(), Comments.find(), etc. and then sort all of those by created_at

Comment: As per zeMirco's answer, you will have to make the same query on each of the collections, and store the results in a composite array that you can then sort once all the queries are run.